# Finding a string after another string

Tags: c#

I have a  string like -----> "12:13:0 james,1324,7656119796027"
I want to  enter james in my program and  get 1234. can you help me with that? thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `1324` - "I want to enter **james** and get **1234**"?

Comment: you'd better give more examples which can represent all possible senarios of input and output.

Comment: This does not seem to be very difficult. Have a look at [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx), [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx), [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Comment: What should happen when u enter '1234'? Or anything that's not in the string? or if there is nothing behind the text you entered?

Comment: Yes exactly!!! I enter james and i wanna get the code which is 1234

Comment: Maybe this?: [`var numAfterInput = Regex.Match(data, string.Format(@"(?<={0}\s*,\s*)\d+", input)).Value`](http://ideone.com/q9Yjvq)

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.IndexOf() to find the index of your input. Just like this:

```
string str = "12:13:0 james,1324,7656119796027";
string key = "james";

int index = str.IndexOf(key);
string stringAfterKey= str.Substring(index + key.Length + 1/*,*/);

string stringYouNeed = stringAfterKey.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0]; // Get 1324, then sort it
```

But please consider there may have multiple indexes that match your keyword. You'd better make your input & output more clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want the first result after comma after your input:

```
private readonly string[] Separators = new string[] { "," };

public void YourMethod()
{
    string result = FindSubstring("james");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private string FindSubstring(string input)
{
    string source = "12:13:0 james,1324,7656119796027";
    int first = source.IndexOf(input) + input.Length;
    string substring = source.Substring(first);

    string[] splittedSubstring = substring.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return splittedSubstring[0];
}
```